# Why does my onClick activate when it is rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

When the the page renders, somehow the `onClick` activates. Why?
How can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react';

function Input(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.on}>
    <div className="input">
        <input placeholder="Ask for help... "/>
        <button onClick={props.setOn("no")}>Send</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: You are executing the function and assigning what it returns to the onClick event handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's because you must pass a function to `onClick`.**
 Here you are not passing a function, you are passing the result of `props.setOn("no")` which is `undefined`. And your function is triggered at the rendering because that's where the `onClick` value of `button` is evaluated and passed, which makes you statement execute.

Try this instead :

```
<button onClick={() => props.setOn("no")}>Send</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I passed through props a parent's useState, and I want to change it when the button is clicked. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Without you whole code it's hard to reply correctly, but one way would be to have a prop on `Input` called like `onSend` and you would pass it to your button this way `<button onClick={onSend}>Send</button>`. Your parent passing it should be something like `<Input on={on} onSend={() => setOn("no")}>`

Comment: I founded the problem! Thank you, for your patient and time!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call on click event like this `onClick={() => props.setOn("no")}`

instead of

```
 Input(props) {
    return (
      <div className={props.on}>
      <div className="input">
          <input placeholder="Ask for help... "/>
          <button onClick={() => props.setOn("no")}>Send</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```